# xml comments displayed in wrong order in Visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2012

I have an dll with xml documentation file.

I have written comment of all member in Persian language.
Persian language is right to left(it means when you write you must write from right of page to left).

I wrote this in English for you to understand what i means:

```
/// <summary>
/// add one to count of users
/// </summary>
public static bool Add
{
    get{...}
}
```

but when i hover on my code visual studio display comments like this : **users of count to one add**

what should I do to solve this?

Comment: Normaly there would be this "*این یک نظر است*" instead of add "*one to count of users*"? If so than I dont think vs supports this kind of language. You should anyway write your comments always in english

Comment: weird, I use VS 2013 and can write Arabic comments from right to left correctly. Can you write Persian correctly in other editors on the same machine. I guess it could be related to regional settings on the machine itself

Comment: No,it is not for that reason you said,tanks.when want to use my dll it does not display it in a correct way.when i hover or pause mouse on my method from that dll vs does not display it correctly.but when intellisens will pop up (when intellisense list will appear) it show comment correctly